# followup response not working for Google Smart home action

Tags: google-api, google-home, google-smart-home

I am trying to implement a follow-up response for a smart home action that was returned as "pending" earlier. I have attached the payload that was sent and also the error from the Google cloud logs.
The log says "GENERIC_ERROR" and does not give more details into it. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Payload sent]

[image: Error log]

The notification fails and the Google smart speaker does not receive any voice notification

Comment: Hi, @nagarjunnadella! This looks like an interesting question, but can you edit it to include the code/error message from the images as code-formatted text instead? Here is a guide that explains about the formatting: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors